# peewee pwiz column data type detection

Tags: peewee

I am using pwiz to generate model classes from an existing mariadb database like this:

```
python -m pwiz -e mysql -u user -P -H host.domain database_name > database_mode.py
```

The model class fields do not exactly reflect the actual data types of the table. A table column of datatype `double` is translated to `FloatField()` although `DoubleField()` exists in peewee. `datetime(6)` is translated to `DateTimeField()`.
Is this expected behaviour?